# c# mvc textboxfor for multiple strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, textbox

Is it possible to have a `Html.TextBoxFor` html helper bound to multiple strings? I mean, say you have one input which the user can either sign in with a username or email. Basically, something like the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName || x.Email) // this does not work obviously, 
                                             // but you got the idea
```

model.cs

```
... 
[Required]
public string UserName {get; set;}

[Required]
public string Email {get; set;}
// btw, the required attribute may cause a problem therefore I can 
// remove or ignore them while validating
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't bind the textbox to either property. Simply handle the code in an Action to check against Username and Email.

If you're creating a login form then you won't be updating either property, so there's no need to bind.

Comment: hmm that's not what I was looking for but thanks for the tip :)